# How do I use Firebase Admin SDK to change data in Firebase Realtime Database while using Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to reset a specific value in my Firebase Realtime Database every day at 12:00 AM. To do this, I'm using the Firebase Admin SDK to change the data in Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Functions to trigger the change at 12:00 AM every day.

This is an example structure of my Firebase Realtime Database:

```
{
  "users": {
    "fa54487d9cbb4214b00db80e2118e4e6": {
      "daily": 10
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code in my `index.js`:

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
var functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Cloud Firestore.
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

// Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
var serviceAccount = require("serviceAccountKey.json");

// Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com"
});

// As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regardless of Security Rules
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("users");

// Reset today GHG emissions at 12:00 AM everyday
exports.dailyReset = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * *').onRun((context) => {
    usersRef.child("{userId}").set({
      daily: 0
    });
});
```

Deploy Error:

> !  functions[dailyReset(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
>
> Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.

Firebase Console Functions Logs:

> Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason.
>
> Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging Function cannot be initialized.
>
> {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":3,"message":"Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code.
>
> Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs.
>
> Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging.

The script won't deploy when I use `firebase deploy` as my function is giving me an error. Can someone tell me how to fix my code?

Comment: The error message is telling you where to go to find the actual error in the console.

Comment: @DougStevenson Are you talking about the log error messages from Firebase Console? If you are, I just included that in my post right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work:

```
exports.dailyReset = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * *').onRun((context) => {
    usersRef.child("{userId}").set({
      daily: 0
    });
});
```

There is nothing here that interprets the `{userId}` in that path, so the database updates the literal path `"/users/{userId}"`, which is not what you want.

If you know what user ID you want to update, you should use that value in the path:

```
exports.dailyReset = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * *').onRun((context) => {
    let usersRef = admin.database().ref("users");
    usersRef.child("theActualUserIdYouWantToUpdate").set({
      daily: 0
    });
});
```

If you don't know what user ID to update, you'll need to [query the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-queries) to determine that.

---

If you want to loop over all users, you can do:

```
exports.dailyReset = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * *').onRun((context) => {
    return usersRef.once("value").then((snapshot) => {
        let updates = {};
        snapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) => {
            updates[userSnapshot.key+"/daily"] = 0
        });
        return usersRef.update(updates);
    });
});
```

If you are new to JavaScript or interacting with the Realtime Database in it, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js process, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Comment: Also you have to return the promise returned by `set()`.

Comment: Since I have to do the value reset for all users I don't know the specific user ID. Would I `orderByChild()`, `orderByKey()`, or `orderByValue()` to do this?

Comment: I added an example of how to loop over all user nodes.

Comment: Should I replace `usersRef` with `ref`? I never created `usersRef` before so I think that also might be a problem. I'm also getting `error  Parsing error: Unexpected token {` with your code.

Comment: I fixed both of those now, but honestly: I **highly** recommend that you try to learn how to interact with the database in a different way first, as these are the sort of mistakes you should be able to fix yourself before you get to the type of use-case that you're trying to implement here.